# How to create elastic Agent Policy and Tokens using Curl

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Trying to setup automatic sandbox environment that requires destroy and rebuild quiet often.
Every time building the sandbox using the docker compose had to manually login to the GUI and add fleet host, create fleet policy, create agent policy, enrolment tokens manually.

What are the Equivalent API for Generate Fleet Server Policy, Agent Policy, Fleet Service Token, Elastic Agent Enrolment Token, Add Fleet Server

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following article.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/8.8/fleet-api-docs.html